# Computing the inverse of a matrix using lapack in C

Tags: c, lapack, matrix-inverse

I would like to be able to compute the inverse of a general `NxN` matrix in C/C++ using lapack.

My understanding is that the way to do an inversion  in lapack is by using the `dgetri` function, however, I can't figure out what all of its arguments are supposed to be.

Here is the code I have:

```
void dgetri_(int* N, double* A, int* lda, int* IPIV, double* WORK, int* lwork, int* INFO);

int main(){

    double M [9] = {
        1,2,3,
        4,5,6,
        7,8,9
    };

    return 0;
}
```

How would you complete it to obtain the inverse of the `3x3` matrix M using dgetri_?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, M has to be a two-dimensional array, like `double M[3][3]`. Your array is, mathematically speaking, a 1x9 vector, which is not invertible.

- N is a pointer to an int for the
  order of the matrix - in this case,
  N=3.
- A is a pointer to the LU
  factorization of the matrix, which
  you can get by running the LAPACK
  routine `dgetrf`.
- LDA is an integer for the "leading
  element" of the matrix, which lets
  you pick out a subset of a bigger
  matrix if you want to just invert a
  little piece. If you want to invert
  the whole matrix, LDA should just be
  equal to N.
- IPIV is the pivot indices of the
  matrix, in other words, it's a list
  of instructions of what rows to swap
  in order to invert the matrix. IPIV
  should be generated by the LAPACK
  routine  `dgetrf`.
- LWORK and WORK are the "workspaces"
  used by LAPACK. If you are inverting
  the whole matrix, LWORK should be an
  int equal to N^2, and WORK should be
  a double array with LWORK elements.
- INFO is just a status variable to
  tell you whether the operation
  completed successfully. Since not all
  matrices are invertible, I would
  recommend that you send this to some
  sort of error-checking system. INFO=0 for successful operation, INFO=-i if the i'th argument had an incorrect input value, and INFO > 0 if the matrix is not invertible.

So, for your code, I would do something like this:

```
int main(){

    double M[3][3] = { {1 , 2 , 3},
                       {4 , 5 , 6},
                       {7 , 8 , 9}}
    double pivotArray[3]; //since our matrix has three rows
    int errorHandler;
    double lapackWorkspace[9];

    // dgetrf(M,N,A,LDA,IPIV,INFO) means invert LDA columns of an M by N matrix 
    // called A, sending the pivot indices to IPIV, and spitting error 
    // information to INFO.
    // also don't forget (like I did) that when you pass a two-dimensional array
    // to a function you need to specify the number of "rows"
    dgetrf_(3,3,M[3][],3,pivotArray[3],&errorHandler);
    //some sort of error check

    dgetri_(3,M[3][],3,pivotArray[3],9,lapackWorkspace,&errorHandler);
    //another error check

    }
```

Comment: Regarding 1x9 or 3x3. There really isn't any difference in terms of memory layout. In fact the BLAS/LAPACK routines don't take 2d arrays. They take 1d arrays and make assumptions about how you've laid it out. Beware though that BLAS and LAPACK will assume FORTRAN ordering (rows change fastest) rather than C ordering.

Comment: You might need `LAPACKE_dgetrf` rather than the fortran routine `dgetrf_`. Ditto `dgetri`. Else you must call everything with addresses.

Answer (score 29):

Here is the working code for computing the inverse of a matrix using lapack in C/C++:

```
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" {
    // LU decomoposition of a general matrix
    void dgetrf_(int* M, int *N, double* A, int* lda, int* IPIV, int* INFO);

    // generate inverse of a matrix given its LU decomposition
    void dgetri_(int* N, double* A, int* lda, int* IPIV, double* WORK, int* lwork, int* INFO);
}

void inverse(double* A, int N)
{
    int *IPIV = new int[N];
    int LWORK = N*N;
    double *WORK = new double[LWORK];
    int INFO;

    dgetrf_(&N,&N,A,&N,IPIV,&INFO);
    dgetri_(&N,A,&N,IPIV,WORK,&LWORK,&INFO);

    delete[] IPIV;
    delete[] WORK;
}

int main(){

    double A [2*2] = {
        1,2,
        3,4
    };

    inverse(A, 2);

    printf("%f %f\n", A[0], A[1]);
    printf("%f %f\n", A[2], A[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to allocate N+1 (but only N unsigned) int for the IPIV variable. Futhermore I don't recommend to use this kind of function to compute the multiples inverses. Allocate the data you need once for all and free at the end only.

Comment: You might need `delete[] IPIV` and `delete [] work`.

Comment: There is no language C/C++. The code you show is C++. But the question is about C.

Comment: Making this valid C code is as simple as changing the `new` calls to `malloc` and the `delete[]` calls to frees (and getting rid of the extern "C").

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working version of the above using OpenBlas interface to LAPACKE.
Link with openblas library (LAPACKE is already contained)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cblas.h"
#include "lapacke.h"

// inplace inverse n x n matrix A.
// matrix A is Column Major (i.e. firts line, second line ... *not* C[][] order)
// returns:
//   ret = 0 on success
//   ret < 0 illegal argument value
//   ret > 0 singular matrix

lapack_int matInv(double *A, unsigned n)
{
    int ipiv[n+1];
    lapack_int ret;

    ret =  LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,
                          n,
                          n,
                          A,
                          n,
                          ipiv);

    if (ret !=0)
        return ret;


    ret = LAPACKE_dgetri(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,
                       n,
                       A,
                       n,
                       ipiv);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    double A[] = {
        0.378589,   0.971711,   0.016087,   0.037668,   0.312398,
        0.756377,   0.345708,   0.922947,   0.846671,   0.856103,
        0.732510,   0.108942,   0.476969,   0.398254,   0.507045,
        0.162608,   0.227770,   0.533074,   0.807075,   0.180335,
        0.517006,   0.315992,   0.914848,   0.460825,   0.731980
    };

    for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
        if ((i%5) == 0) putchar('\n');
        printf("%+12.8f ",A[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    matInv(A,5);

    for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
        if ((i%5) == 0) putchar('\n');
        printf("%+12.8f ",A[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Example:

```
% g++ -I [OpenBlas path]/include/ example.cpp [OpenBlas path]/lib/libopenblas.a
% a.out

+0.37858900  +0.97171100  +0.01608700  +0.03766800  +0.31239800 
+0.75637700  +0.34570800  +0.92294700  +0.84667100  +0.85610300 
+0.73251000  +0.10894200  +0.47696900  +0.39825400  +0.50704500 
+0.16260800  +0.22777000  +0.53307400  +0.80707500  +0.18033500 
+0.51700600  +0.31599200  +0.91484800  +0.46082500  +0.73198000 

+0.24335255  -2.67946180  +3.57538817  +0.83711880  +0.34704217 
+1.02790497  -1.05086895  -0.07468137  +0.71041070  +0.66708313 
-0.21087237  -4.47765165  +1.73958308  +1.73999641  +3.69324020 
-0.14100897  +2.34977565  -0.93725915  +0.47383541  -2.15554470 
-0.26329660  +6.46315378  -4.07721533  -3.37094863  -2.42580445
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of Spencer Nelson's example above. One mystery about it is that the input matrix is in row-major order, even though it appears to call the underlying fortran routine `dgetri`.  I am led to believe that all the underlying fortran routines require column-major order, but I am no expert on LAPACK, in fact, I'm using this example to help me learn it.  But, that one mystery aside:

The input matrix in the example is singular. LAPACK tries to tell you that by returning a `3` in the `errorHandler`.  I changed the `9` in that matrix to a `19`, getting an `errorHandler` of `0` signalling success, and compared the result to that from `Mathematica`. The comparison was also successful and confirmed that the matrix in the example should be in row-major order, as presented.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

int main() {
    int N = 3;
    int NN = 9;
    double M[3][3] = { {1 , 2 , 3},
                       {4 , 5 , 6},
                       {7 , 8 , 9} };
    int pivotArray[3]; //since our matrix has three rows
    int errorHandler;
    double lapackWorkspace[9];

    // dgetrf(M,N,A,LDA,IPIV,INFO) means invert LDA columns of an M by N matrix
    // called A, sending the pivot indices to IPIV, and spitting error information
    // to INFO. also don't forget (like I did) that when you pass a two-dimensional
    // array to a function you need to specify the number of "rows"
    dgetrf_(&N, &N, M[0], &N, pivotArray, &errorHandler);
    printf ("dgetrf eh, %d, should be zero\n", errorHandler);

    dgetri_(&N, M[0], &N, pivotArray, lapackWorkspace, &NN, &errorHandler);
    printf ("dgetri eh, %d, should be zero\n", errorHandler);

    for (size_t row = 0; row < N; ++row)
    {   for (size_t col = 0; col < N; ++col)
        {   printf ("%g", M[row][col]);
            if (N-1 != col)
            {   printf (", ");   }   }
        if (N-1 != row)
        {   printf ("\n");   }   }

    return 0;   }
```

I built and ran it as follows on a Mac:

```
gcc main.c -llapacke -llapack
./a.out
```

I did an `nm` on the LAPACKE library and found the following:

```
liblapacke.a(lapacke_dgetri.o):
                 U _LAPACKE_dge_nancheck
0000000000000000 T _LAPACKE_dgetri
                 U _LAPACKE_dgetri_work
                 U _LAPACKE_xerbla
                 U _free
                 U _malloc

liblapacke.a(lapacke_dgetri_work.o):
                 U _LAPACKE_dge_trans
0000000000000000 T _LAPACKE_dgetri_work
                 U _LAPACKE_xerbla
                 U _dgetri_
                 U _free
                 U _malloc
```

and it looks like there is a LAPACKE [sic] wrapper that would presumably relieve us of having to take addresses everywhere for fortran's convenience, but I am probably not going to get around to trying it because I have a way forward.

**EDIT**

Here is a working version that bypasses LAPACKE [sic], using LAPACK fortran routines directly.  I do not understand why a row-major input produces correct results, but I confirmed it again in Mathematica.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main() {
    int N = 3;
    int NN = 9;
    double M[3][3] = { {1 , 2 ,  3},
                       {4 , 5 ,  6},
                       {7 , 8 , 19} };
    int pivotArray[3]; //since our matrix has three rows
    int errorHandler;
    double lapackWorkspace[9];
    /* from http://www.netlib.no/netlib/lapack/double/dgetrf.f
      SUBROUTINE DGETRF( M, N, A, LDA, IPIV, INFO )
      *
      *  -- LAPACK routine (version 3.1) --
      *     Univ. of Tennessee, Univ. of California Berkeley and NAG Ltd..
      *     November 2006
      *
      *     .. Scalar Arguments ..
      INTEGER            INFO, LDA, M, N
      *     ..
      *     .. Array Arguments ..
      INTEGER            IPIV( * )
      DOUBLE PRECISION   A( LDA, * )
    */

    extern void dgetrf_ (int * m, int * n, double * A, int * LDA, int * IPIV,
                         int * INFO);

    /* from http://www.netlib.no/netlib/lapack/double/dgetri.f
       SUBROUTINE DGETRI( N, A, LDA, IPIV, WORK, LWORK, INFO )
       *
       *  -- LAPACK routine (version 3.1) --
       *     Univ. of Tennessee, Univ. of California Berkeley and NAG Ltd..
       *     November 2006
       *
       *     .. Scalar Arguments ..
       INTEGER            INFO, LDA, LWORK, N
       *     ..
       *     .. Array Arguments ..
       INTEGER            IPIV( * )
       DOUBLE PRECISION   A( LDA, * ), WORK( * )
    */

    extern void dgetri_ (int * n, double * A, int * LDA, int * IPIV,
                         double * WORK, int * LWORK, int * INFO);

    // dgetrf(M,N,A,LDA,IPIV,INFO) means invert LDA columns of an M by N matrix
    // called A, sending the pivot indices to IPIV, and spitting error information
    // to INFO. also don't forget (like I did) that when you pass a two-dimensional
    // array to a function you need to specify the number of "rows"
    dgetrf_(&N, &N, M[0], &N, pivotArray, &errorHandler);
    printf ("dgetrf eh, %d, should be zero\n", errorHandler);

    dgetri_(&N, M[0], &N, pivotArray, lapackWorkspace, &NN, &errorHandler);
    printf ("dgetri eh, %d, should be zero\n", errorHandler);

    for (size_t row = 0; row < N; ++row)
    {   for (size_t col = 0; col < N; ++col)
        {   printf ("%g", M[row][col]);
            if (N-1 != col)
            {   printf (", ");   }   }
        if (N-1 != row)
        {   printf ("\n");   }   }
    return 0;   }
```

built and run like this:

```
$ gcc foo.c -llapack
$ ./a.out
dgetrf eh, 0, should be zero
dgetri eh, 0, should be zero
-1.56667, 0.466667, 0.1
1.13333, 0.0666667, -0.2
0.1, -0.2, 0.1
```

**EDIT**

The mystery no longer appears to be a mystery.  I think the computations are being done in column-major order, as they must, but I am both inputting and printing the matrices as if they were in row-major order. I have two  bugs that cancel each other out so things look row-ish even though they're column-ish.