# How do I install C packages on windows

Tags: c, package, lapack

I have to use LU decompostion to fit a simple model to some data (simulated) in C. An example of what I need to do is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519959/computing-the-inverse-of-a-matrix-using-lapack-in-c):

However, I'm stuck with a more basic problem: how do I install packages in C and call them in my code?

I'm new in C and I'm used to R. But I have this assingment to do some tests about Matrix inversion, LU decomposision and the professor suggested using Lapack to easy things (thus, I don't need to code myself the LU decomposition etc.). But I don't know how to install the package and call it in my code, in order to use the functions of LAPACK.

I have a windows 7 64 bits and I'm using compiler Code Blocks 8.02

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. I learned how to use external libraries, but I'm still with problems with Lapack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally you don't "install" C libraries in that sense. Normally, in Windows you have three types of files. The header files, typically ending in .h, the dynamic library, .dll, and most likely some linker files (typically, .lib, .a or something). The linker and compiler will need to be able to find these files somewhere. Normally you set the include directory paths, and library directory paths.

E.g. Let's say you downloaded a library called foo, and you extract it to C:\foo.
In that folder, `libfoo.a`, `foo.dll` and `foo.h` reside. In Code::Blocks you will have to point include directory path to `C:\foo` and library path to `C:\foo` so that the linker and compiler know where to look for these files. Since you're linking against the foo library, you will also have to set `-lfoo` or something similiar in linker command line. This is GCC syntax, but I think Code::Blocks uses GCC compiler behind the scenes anyways.

In the C code you can just `#include <foo.h>` and the compiler will find it for you.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like exactly the kind of instruction I needed. I will give it a try and get back here telling if it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install that library and it might actually supply a [tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_system) for that. Check their documentation (e.g. a file `INSTALL` or `README` in their distributed sources). If the library uses only headers you might only need to copy it's headers to some directory on your system, but their buildsystem might be able to do that for you.

Once that is done you would tell your IDE on where to look for the sources and if the library uses not just headers to link against the actual library file. See the documentation in [the Code::Blocks Wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=User_documentation#Third-party_libraries) on how this is done for some example cases and adapt for your library.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do in your situation is to install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  You can use the setup.exe installer to install the GCC and the LAPACK libraries.  When you want to use the LAPACK library, you will add the -llapack option to your GCC command line.