# Error while importing enchant from pyenchant on windows

Tags: python, pyenchant

I have installed pyenchant on my system, but when I run "import enchant" command, I get an error telling me "The enchant 'C' library was not found". I have tried installing Abiword word processor to install enchant separately, so to speak. But still getting the same error.

I have read the solutions in ["enchant C library not found" while installing pyenchant using pip on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083059/cannot-install-pyenchant), but that is for Mac and I am running on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the C library called Enchant. I have problems myself to install C libraries, but surely downloading Enchant will be a first step.

This post gives some explanation about how to install a C library:

[How do I install C packages on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737414/how-do-i-install-c-packages-on-windows)

but I have to admit this did not solve quite my problem. Do not hesitate to update if find more info.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the version of pyenchant. You need to first check what is the version of pyenchant installed on your machine.
For Unix based systems you can run (Please find suitable windows command)

- pip show pyenchant

Then install below version :
pip install pyenchant==2.0.0

Let me know if this works for you.