# Run time bug on matlab MEX file

Tags: matlab, mex

I have struggling with an implementation of MEX file, I get run time error!
    I would like to given two inputs : inMatToInv, inMatToMul I would like to compute : inv(inMatToInv)*inMatToMul, I assume that the user enters only 3x3 matrices. 
    I also assume that the inMatToInv in invertible.

```
    /*==========================================================
 * inv_and_mul_3by3.c 
 * inverse 3x3 matrix and multiply it by another 3x3 matrix
 * The calling syntax is: outMatrix = (mat_to_inv,mat_to_mul)
 *========================================================*/

#include "mex.h"

/* The computational routine */
void inv_and_mul_3by3(double *mat_to_inv, double *mat_to_mul, double *out)
{
    // Description : out = inv(mat_to_inv)*mat_to_mul
    double *inversed;
    double det;

    /* Calculate the matrix deteminant */
    det = mat_to_inv[0]*(mat_to_inv[4]*mat_to_inv[8]-mat_to_inv[7]*mat_to_inv[5]) - mat_to_inv[3]*(mat_to_inv[1]*mat_to_inv[8]-mat_to_inv[7]*mat_to_inv[2])+mat_to_inv[6]*(mat_to_inv[1]*mat_to_inv[5]-mat_to_inv[4]*mat_to_inv[2]);

    // Calcualte the inversed matrix
    inversed[0] = (mat_to_inv[4]*mat_to_inv[8] - mat_to_inv[7]*mat_to_inv[5])/det;
    inversed[3] = (mat_to_inv[6]*mat_to_inv[5] - mat_to_inv[3]*mat_to_inv[8])/det;
    inversed[6] = (mat_to_inv[3]*mat_to_inv[7] - mat_to_inv[6]*mat_to_inv[4])/det;
    inversed[1] = (mat_to_inv[7]*mat_to_inv[2] - mat_to_inv[1]*mat_to_inv[8])/det;
    inversed[4] = (mat_to_inv[0]*mat_to_inv[8] - mat_to_inv[6]*mat_to_inv[2])/det;
    inversed[7] = (mat_to_inv[6]*mat_to_inv[1] - mat_to_inv[0]*mat_to_inv[7])/det;
    inversed[2] = (mat_to_inv[1]*mat_to_inv[5] - mat_to_inv[4]*mat_to_inv[2])/det;
    inversed[5] = (mat_to_inv[3]*mat_to_inv[2] - mat_to_inv[0]*mat_to_inv[5])/det;
    inversed[8] = (mat_to_inv[0]*mat_to_inv[4] - mat_to_inv[3]*mat_to_inv[1])/det;

    out[0] = inversed[0]*mat_to_mul[0] + inversed[3]*mat_to_mul[1] + inversed[6]*mat_to_mul[2];
    out[1] = inversed[1]*mat_to_mul[0] + inversed[4]*mat_to_mul[1] + inversed[7]*mat_to_mul[2];
    out[2] = inversed[2]*mat_to_mul[0] + inversed[5]*mat_to_mul[1] + inversed[8]*mat_to_mul[2];
    out[3] = inversed[0]*mat_to_mul[3] + inversed[3]*mat_to_mul[4] + inversed[6]*mat_to_mul[5];
    out[4] = inversed[1]*mat_to_mul[3] + inversed[4]*mat_to_mul[4] + inversed[7]*mat_to_mul[5];
    out[5] = inversed[2]*mat_to_mul[3] + inversed[5]*mat_to_mul[4] + inversed[8]*mat_to_mul[5];
    out[6] = inversed[0]*mat_to_mul[6] + inversed[3]*mat_to_mul[7] + inversed[6]*mat_to_mul[8];
    out[7] = inversed[1]*mat_to_mul[6] + inversed[4]*mat_to_mul[7] + inversed[7]*mat_to_mul[8];
    out[8] = inversed[2]*mat_to_mul[6] + inversed[5]*mat_to_mul[7] + inversed[8]*mat_to_mul[8];
}

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *inMatToInv;             /* 3x3 input matrix that is inversed */
    double *inMatToMul;             /* 3x3 input matrix that multiply the inversed matrix*/ 
    double *outMatrix;              /* 3x3 output matrix */

    /* create pointers to the real data in the input matrix  */
    inMatToInv = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    inMatToMul = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

    /* create the output matrix */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(3,3,mxREAL);

    /* get a pointer to the real data in the output matrix */
    outMatrix = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    /* call the computational routine */
    inv_and_mul_3by3(inMatToInv,inMatToMul,outMatrix);
}
```

any help will be much appreciated. 
Thanks, 
Tamir

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it's good practice to verify number and size of inputs in the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a pointer `double *inversed`, but you do not allocate any memory for it. So when you access `inversed[0]` you get an error. Try:

```
double inversed[9];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [blas](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) and [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/index.html) interface for matrix operations in a C mex file. Have a look at Mathworks documentation on doing this [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-lapack-and-blas-functions-from-mex-files.html).

You would be interested in the lapack routines `dgetrf` and `dgetri` for the matrix inversion and `dgemm` for matrix multiplication. The lapack interface can be really messy and difficult to grasp but there are lots of references online about them. For example, [this stack overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519959/computing-the-inverse-of-a-matrix-using-lapack-in-c).