# Specific math functions in C++ used by techwinder

Tags: smoothing, matrix, c++

In [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/55439/59291)
[@techwinder](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/40544/techwinder) used in his-own code functions:

- `matMult()` with 6 args where are this function from?
- Also where I could find functions: `invert33()`, `invert44()`, `inverseMatrixLapack()`, and `matMult()`, which are used in [@techwinder](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/40544/techwinder) code?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I think you should have asked himself :) maybe this will be closed or moved to stackoverflow...

Just to shed some light on the subject,
he mentions [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), in the code.

You can find out how to compute the inverse matrix with lapack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519959/computing-the-inverse-of-a-matrix-using-lapack-in-c), and matrix-matrix multiplication can be computed with [dgemm](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d54/group__double__blas__level3_gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1.html)

He has some specialized code for small matrix, but that is not necessary if you want a simple solution.